# Check String For Consecutive Pairs C++

Tags: c++

I'm looking to write a C++ console app that takes in lines of text from a .txt file, which I have done, now what I need to do is check each line for consecutive pairs of letters

**"For example, the word “tooth” has one pair of double letters, and the word “committee” has two pairs of consecutive double letters."**

Should I convert each line into a Cstring and loop through each character? I really don't know where to start with this.

I'm not looking for someone to write out the entire solution, I just need to know how to start this.

Comment: Perhaps you can start [by scheduling an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: `if(str[i] == str[i + 1]) ++couny;`

Comment: Could look into using [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

Comment: IMHO, stay away from CString.  Use something more portable such as `std::string`.

Comment: Open the stream, read a word (`is >> word`), find, count.

Comment: Does the text "aaa" contain one pair of double letters or two (according to your requirement)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, it would have to be 2 consecutive pairs aaa would only be one pair while aaaa would be two pairs.

Comment: Regardless of what you do, you're going to need to look through each character. You can't avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the string from start to the second last `char` and compare 2 `char`s at a time. In C++17 you have `std::string_view` which is handy.

```
#include <string_view>

size_t pair_count(std::string_view s) {
    size_t rv = 0; // the result 

    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < s.size() - 1; ++idx) {
        // compare s[idx] and s[idx+1]
        // if they are equal, increase rv by one
        // and increase idx by one (if you want "aaa" to count as 1 and not 2)
    }

    return rv;
}
```